# Can a phonegap based app launch a task by itself?

Tags: cordova

I am planning to use phonegap to develop an app. My requirement is to check status of something over internet and then if a change is detected then report to the user. In Android I accomplished this by writing a background Service that gets invoked say at 10:00 AM every morning.

Is this something that we can do with phonegap framework?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this without native functionality. On Android your approach will work fine; if necessary you can write a small plugin to register/unregister your service.

On iOS however you should use the push notification service for this purpose. Set up a simple server-side script that regularly checks the target URL and caches the result in e.g. an HTML file. If the new file differs from the cached file, call the push notification service.

I've done this for a few apps. To keep it simple and prevent yourself from having to dive into Objective-C, you could use e.g. [UrbanAirship](http://urbanairship.com) and [its PhoneGap plugin](https://github.com/urbanairship/phonegap-ua-push) to take care of the notificaions for you.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. This gives me some direction and premise as to what to look for..